# R: How to arrange a data frame in order to display columns

Tags: r

I have the following code and data frames

```
CONSUMO<-data.frame( 9914282, 10375040, 10618441, 10547759)
INVERSION<-data.frame( 2860302
, 3017084, 29452363, 2917028)
IMPORTACIONES<-data.frame(3966992, 4183838,4244597,4274534)
EXPORTACIONES<-data.frame( 9914282, 4168771,4217287, 4427378)

PIB<-(CONSUMO+INVERSION+EXPORTACIONES-IMPORTACIONES)
PIB
## X9914282 X10375040 X10618441 X10547759
## 1 18721874 13377057 40043494 13617631
PERIODO<-data.frame(2011,2012,2013,2014)
```

I use this code to put all the data together

```
Tabla7<-data.frame(c(PERIODO,CONSUMO,INVERSION, EXPORTACIONES, 
IMPORTACIONES, PIB))
```

it is displayed like this:

```
Tabla7
## X2011 X2012 X2013 X2014 X9914282 X10375040 X10618441 X10547759 X2860302
## 1 2011 2012 2013 2014 9914282 10375040 10618441 10547759 2860302
## X3017084 X29452363 X2917028 X9914282.1 X4168771 X4217287 X4427378
## 1 3017084 29452363 2917028 9914282 4168771 4217287 4427378
## X3966992 X4183838 X4244597 X4274534 X9914282.2 X10375040.1 X10618441.1
## 1 3966992 4183838 4244597 4274534 18721874 13377057 40043494
## X10547759.1
## 1 13617631
```

My question is how to display the new data frame that looks like a table,  so  PERIODO CONSUMO INVERSION  EXPORTACIONES IMPORTACIONES PIB quantities are displayed in different columns and its values shown vertically.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted, it looks like you've mistaken `data.frame()` with the combine function `c()`.  The combine function `c()` is used to create data vectors with non-sequential numbers.

The last step should use `data.frame()` to build the data frame, which will correctly render the vectors as columns.

```
> CONSUMO<-c( 9914282, 10375040, 10618441, 10547759)
> INVERSION<-c( 2860302, 3017084, 29452363, 2917028)
> IMPORTACIONES<-c(3966992, 4183838,4244597,4274534)
> EXPORTACIONES<-c( 9914282, 4168771,4217287, 4427378)
> 
> PIB<-(CONSUMO+INVERSION+EXPORTACIONES-IMPORTACIONES)
> PERIODO<-c(2011,2012,2013,2014)
> 
> theData <- data.frame(PERIODO, CONSUMO, INVERSION, IMPORTACIONES, EXPORTACIONES, PIB)
> theData
  PERIODO  CONSUMO INVERSION IMPORTACIONES EXPORTACIONES      PIB
1    2011  9914282   2860302       3966992       9914282 18721874
2    2012 10375040   3017084       4183838       4168771 13377057
3    2013 10618441  29452363       4244597       4217287 40043494
4    2014 10547759   2917028       4274534       4427378 13617631
>
```

regards,

Len